# Configurate taxes for payment types in Magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment, tax

I would like to include a tax of 1€ when customer selects "Cash on Delivery" payment method and
2% when selects  "Paypal".

Is there a way to implement this?

Thank you

Comment: cart price rules

Comment: not really. This is for apply a discount as i see, and i can't choose a condition as "payment method" . I t would be great if you explain some more steps that i have to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Including tax is not possible due to heavy customization, If you provide like fees amount than Please check with below extension to apply charges filter with payment method.

https://github.com/mrkhoa99/Boolfly_payment_fee

Comment: That's It,Thank you!